# graphics mode on install

Tags: via

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 or any version from a thumb drive onto an HP t5565 thin client. The install crashes when it trys to init graphics. I've installed Linux Mint 13 by using safe mode but can not understand how to get Ubuntu to install into low graphics.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the pics of keyboard and man when it boots - hit any key.

You can then choose various boot options - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options

I think that F4 at that screen has safe mode as an option.